# How to choose a font for a website?

Tags: design, fonts, typography, website-design

How to choose a font for a website that is readable,usable,authority ?

Comment: your question is better suited for doctype.com

Comment: Can you give us more information?  "readable" makes sense, but "usable" and "authority" I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 2):

Verdana is for me the most readable font. And I think serif fonts are very hard to read on screen...

Comment: Georgia is very readable, since it was designed for the screen rather than print.

Comment: Yes, Georgia is a good serif font for screen reading, but I really read more easily sans serif fonts... It's just my feeling ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is cool:

1. find a site with font you like
2. take a screenshot of it and submit it to this:  http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
3. it will try to tell you what font it is.
4. look it up on a font website and use it.

Comment: That doesn't mean the font is easy to read or available on all systems. That just helps you find the font you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add line-height. It turns horrible looking text into much more readable and better looking text. Whitespace FTW

Answer (score 0):

You generally are best off using "Serif" and "Sans-Serif", which lets the operating system pick the user's (and probably best) font.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the typography for a website is part of the web design process. I recommend hiring a professional web designer to design your site for you.

Answer (score 0):

Find a font that works with your overall design.  These days you can use a javascript framework to use any font you like (licsencing does apply).  I use SIFR to format fonts for my website.  I usually only use it for H1 - H2 tags and limit it to certian text.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments, echoed by other comments:

1. "Readable" is subjective, and depends largely on the available equipment of your target market
2. "Usable" is dependent on the OS and browser in use by your target market
3. "Authority" is... wait, what? ;)

My suggestion: consider the fonts most readily available to the majority of operating systems, and the majority of browsers, and ensure your CSS/HTML allows for them, in order of preference.  Design around that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the site. Its quite kool for your font selection. gives detail idea with comparisions:

http://www.wilsonweb.com/wmt6/html-email-fonts.htm

Its KOOL[Sunshine Trekking](http://www.sunshinetrekking.com)/[Trekking and Tours](http://trekkingandtoursnepal.com)